# How to reformat the data from Blogger API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, blogger

I'm creating an app for my new blog, which is hosted on blogger.com. I've got the posts to get displayed in the app along with the images, but for some reason I can't get the text in the post to be formatted. It has just bunched it all together.

Here's how it looks in the blog & in the app:
[image]

How can I format this in my code so that it looks like it does in the blog?

Here's the code I'm using in the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'pages/post_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _isLoading = true; //For progress bar
  var posts;
  var imgUrl;
  //initialization
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }
  //Function to fetch data from JSON
  @override
  _fetchData() async {
    print("attempting");
    final url =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8902712678213444829/posts/?key=AIzaSyDpwI-kMZ_IxqAJVBKAVtWLOlaGQ5YLEuw";
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) { 
      //HTTP OK is 200
      final Map items = json.decode(response.body);
      var post = items['items'];

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        this.posts = post;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Blogger"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true;
                  });
                  _fetchData();
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: _isLoading
                ? new CircularProgressIndicator()
                : new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: this.posts != null ? this.posts.length : 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      final post = this.posts[i];
                      final postDesc = post["content"];
                      //All the below code is to fetch the image
                      var document = parse(postDesc);
                      //Regular expression
                      RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
                        r"(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif))",
                        caseSensitive: false,
                        multiLine: false,
                      );
                      final match = regExp
                          .stringMatch(document.outerHtml.toString())
                          .toString();
                      //print(document.outerHtml);
                      //print("firstMatch : " + match);
                      //Converting the regex output to image (Slashing) , since the output from regex was not perfect for me
                      if (match.length > 5) {
                        if (match.contains(".jpg")) {
                          imgUrl = match.substring(0, match.indexOf(".jpg"));
                          print(imgUrl);
                        } else {
                          imgUrl =
                              "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8902712678213444829/posts/?key=AIzaSyDpwI-kMZ_IxqAJVBKAVtWLOlaGQ5YLEuw";
                        }
                      }
                      String description = document.body.text.trim();
                      //print(description);

                      return new Container(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 8.0),
                        child: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              width: 500.0,
                              height: 180.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                    //check if the image is not null (length > 5) only then check imgUrl else display default img
                                    image: new NetworkImage(imgUrl
                                                .toString()
                                                .length >
                                            10
                                        ? imgUrl.toString()
                                        : "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8902712678213444829/posts/?key=AIzaSyDpwI-kMZ_IxqAJVBKAVtWLOlaGQ5YLEuw")),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                post["title"],
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Text(
                              description.replaceAll("\n", ", "),
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                            ),
                            new Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                              child: new RaisedButton(
                                child: new Text("READ MORE",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  //We will pass description to postview through an argument
                                  Navigator
                                      .of(context)
                                      .push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return PostView(post['title'],description,imgUrl);
                                    },
                                  ));
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )));
  }
}
```

And here's the code I'm using in the post_view.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostView extends StatelessWidget {
  var desc, title, image;

  PostView(String title, String desc, String image) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (desc.toString().contains("\n\n\n\n")) {
      desc = desc.toString().replaceAll("\n\n\n\n", "\n\n");
    }

    if (desc.toString().contains("\n\n\n")) {
      desc = desc.toString().replaceAll("\n\n\n", "\n");
    }
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Blogger"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: new Text(
              title,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: new Container(
              width: 500.0,
              height: 180.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    //check if the image is not null (length > 5) only then check imgUrl else display default img
                    image: new NetworkImage(image.toString().length > 10
                        ? image.toString()
                        : "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8902712678213444829/posts/?key=AIzaSyDpwI-kMZ_IxqAJVBKAVtWLOlaGQ5YLEuw")),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: new Text(
              desc,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ))),
    );
  }
}
```

EDITED:
Here's what get's printed in the console when I hot reload the app:

```
I/flutter ( 9778): attempting
I/flutter ( 9778): {
I/flutter ( 9778):   "kind": "blogger#postList",
I/flutter ( 9778):   "items": [
I/flutter ( 9778):     {
I/flutter ( 9778):       "kind": "blogger#post",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "id": "3086822326789809431",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "blog": {
I/flutter ( 9778):         "id": "8902712678213444829"
I/flutter ( 9778):       },
I/flutter ( 9778):       "published": "2020-06-15T00:22:00-07:00",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "updated": "2020-06-15T22:19:56-07:00",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "url": "http://lessmeatapp.blogspot.com/2020/06/mushroom-tagine.html",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8902712678213444829/posts/3086822326789809431",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "title": "Dummy Post 3",
I/flutter ( 9778):       "content": "\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv9KcxNHxhU/XuhVnskHvCI/AAAAAAAAAGw/z7tH271PrIEvkQam74G497Gw4A-eFondACK4BGAsYHg/s1400/DD-Grunge-United-Kingdom-Flag-88837-Preview.jpg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"\u003e\u003cimg border=\"0\" data-original-height=\"980\" data-original-width=\"1400\" src=\"https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv9KcxNHxhU/XuhVnskHvCI/AAAAAAAAAGw/z7tH271PrIEvkQam74G497G
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv9KcxNHxhU/XuhVnskHvCI/AAAAAAAAAGw/z7tH271PrIEvkQam74G497Gw4A-eFondACK4BGAsYHg/s1400/DD-Grunge-United-Kingdom-Flag-88837-Preview
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hvzDDsO44FI/XuhWvqDjRwI/AAAAAAAAAHI/mBjWane0s5wtdJnkLDrNrmyprVoNeWDagCK4BGAsYHg/s1400/DD-Patriotic-Retro-Background-33092-Preview
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-efv2-Ikiyr8/XuhX-YLtDDI/AAAAAAAAAH0/JJE2mrOU-HMsq6Adu1whv5b3W10yqkRlQCK4BGAsYHg/s1400/20
```

Comment: your response is HTML?

Comment: Hi @veneno, what do you mean by that? Sorry still fairly new to coding

Comment: your `fetchData` method has a `reponse` variable, and you print it, just copy it and paste your response value here

Comment: Here's console info: ```I/flutter ( 9778): attempting
I/flutter ( 9778): Instance of 'Response'
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv9KcxNHxhU/XuhVnskHvCI/AAAAAAAAAGw/z7tH271PrIEvkQam74G497Gw4A-eFondACK4BGAsYHg/s1400/DD-Grunge-United-Kingdom-Flag-88837-Preview
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hvzDDsO44FI/XuhWvqDjRwI/AAAAAAAAAHI/mBjWane0s5wtdJnkLDrNrmyprVoNeWDagCK4BGAsYHg/s1400/DD-Patriotic-Retro-Background-33092-Preview
I/flutter ( 9778): https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-efv2-Ikiyr8/XuhX-YLtDDI/AAAAAAAAAH0/JJE2mrOU-HMsq6Adu1whv5b3W10yqkRlQCK4BGAsYHg/s1400/20
```

Comment: In html new line is `<br>` or `<p>..</p>`, so maybe your desc does not have new lines? Would be nice to see what is inside desc

Comment: @JasonLloyd that's my mistake, please print `reponse.body` specially desc section

Comment: @veneno please see edited post for this

Answer (score 1):

in response, `content` section is HTML

and for render HTML in the flutter, you should use `fultter_html` package

[you can find it in this link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)

and with this, you don't need export images from your content

if you have any question ask me in comments

in your `PostView` build method pass description variable to HTML widget:

```
Html(
      data: description,
      //Optional parameters:
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
```

Comment: Hi @veneno, thank you for your answer. Ok, I've had a play around with the flutter_html package example. I can see that it basically converts html to dart, so I can see how that is useful. The question I now have is - How do I implement this back into my current code? I'm really confused. I have copied and pasted the html from the api, and that gets displayed fine in the example. But I don't want to hardcode html into the app, because I need it to read directly from the blog. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help

Comment: your welcome, you just need pass `description` variable to HTML widget, I add a sample code